# Are there any nuances between "dismiss" and "ignore"?

Tags: comparison

According to the ODE, to *dismiss* something (e.g. an idea) means:

> 2. Treat as unworthy of serious consideration.
>
>    > 2.1 Deliberately cease to think about.

And to *ignore* something, still according to the ODE, means:

> Refuse to take notice of or acknowledge; disregard intentionally.

Is there really any difference at all between these two definitions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ignore and dismiss are not synonyms and can hardly ever replace each other.

**Ignore = skip without paying attention**

You see something and *immediately* decide to not pay attention to it, which means you ignore it.

> "I recognized him on the street but **ignored** him." (which means, I saw him and just went past him without saying anything)

or

> "He ignored insulting remarks."

**Dismiss = check and discard**

You hear something, *start to think about it,* but then recognize it as unworthy, so you "cease to think about it", which means you dismiss it.

> "After a short discussion, he **dismissed** the idea."

"Dismiss" is often used when dealing with people.

> "The teacher has **dismissed** the class." (which means let them go after the lesson is finished).

or

> "There are more and more reports that patients are being **dismissed** by
>   their doctors." (which means a doctor had some patients, who visited him
>   several times, but later he decided he doesn't want them as
>   patient any more, so he dismissed them).